# Button executes but does not highlight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

So I have a project where my button is placed in:

```
View -> Scroll View -> Stack View -> View -> Stack View -> Button
```

All my codes with the button are working fine. However, it does not get highlighted(?).

[This is what the normal blue buttons are SUPPOSED TO look like when its pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tijGS.png)

However, the button inside my stackview does not respond. Meaning that you can't really tell whether the button is really pressed or not.

Anyone know what might be causing the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `delaysContentTouches` to `false` on your `UIScrollView` or uncheck it from your storyboard. Otherwise the button will be highlighted with a delay.